# Any recommendation on tools for doing translations / localization in .NET?

Tags: .net, internationalization

We have made use of Passolo for a number of years, but it's kind of clunky and overpriced.

It's got to be able to handle winforms and WPF....

Are there any open source alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Your question could use some clarification as to exactly what aspects of translation / localization you need help with.  Do you need help extracting strings from code?  Tracking down improper use of non-localizable String.Formats in code (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy vs. dd/mm/yyyy)?  Help managing all the resources once you've extracted them?  Help managing the actual translation process while working with translators?

There are many aspects to consider.  That having been said, some tools I am currently evaluating are:

Multi-Language Add-In for Visual Studio
http://www.jollans.com/tiki/tiki-index.php?page=multilangvsnet

Sisulizer
http://www.sisulizer.com/

RGreatEx (requires Resharper, which we use)
http://www.safedevelop.com

I also got a lot out of reading ".NET Internationalization" by Guy Smith-Ferrier, ISBN 0-321-34138-4.  He provides some downloadable tools of his own design.

Answer (score 2):

Coincidentally I saw this on MS Channel 9 this morning - Babylon.NET http://www.redpin.eu/
Sadly I can't vouch for it as I haven't used it, but looks like a reasonable alternative to Passolo (well, at least it's cheaper).